# Index's for largest and smallest values in Vector

Tags: c++, vector

If the following code returns the index for the smallest value in the vector:

```
std::min_element(prices.begin(), prices.end()) - prices.begin();
```

Then why doesn't this code return the index for the largest value in the vector?

```
std::max_element(prices.begin(), prices.end()) - prices.begin();
```

EDIT: Example vector.

```
vector<int> prices{30, 20, 18, 15, 50}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please include real code in your question, as a [mcve], instead of fantasy code. `vector prices{30, 20, 18, 15, 50}` is not valid C++ code. When corrected to "std::vector<int> prices{30, 20, 18, 15, 50};", this works as expected.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik, Calm down, that is the real code. `#include <vector>`  
`using std::vector;` is at the top. Yes my bad I forgot to include the `<int>` part. @juanchopanza, thank you for the edit.

Comment: As I wrote, this works as expected. `std::cout << (std::max_element(prices.begin(), prices.end()) - prices.begin()) << std::endl;` results in `4`, which is correct.

Comment: @Tahmid -- That's why you should have posted a [mcve], so that we can see how you're verifying that the index is not correct.  You didn't even assign or output the return value of `std::min_element` or `std::max_element`, leading to believe your real code does much more than what you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine and as expected.
The index of first element is zero

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> prices{30, 20, 18, 15, 50};
    int min_index = std::min_element(prices.begin(), prices.end()) - prices.begin();
    int max_index = std::max_element(prices.begin(), prices.end()) - prices.begin();
    std::cout<<"Minimum position: "<<min_index+1<<endl;
    std::cout<<"Minimum position: "<<max_index+1<<endl;
}
```

The 
output:
Minimum position: 4

Minimum position: 5